# C# 4.0 Excel Generate Chart and Position

Tags: c#, .net, excel, charts

I ran into a little problem. I've created a code that creates a Excel sheet with a few records and creates a line chart. But the problem is I cant seem to position the chart at a specified position. Here is my code:

```
 excelApp.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select();
 excelApp.ActiveChart.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
 excelApp.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(Source: excelApp.Range["Sheet1!$A$1:$B$7"]);
 excelApp.ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "mainChartView";
 excelApp.ActiveChart.Shapes.Item(excelApp.ActiveChart.Name).Top = 100; 
 // or excelApp.ActiveChart.Shapes.Item("mainChartView").Top = 100;
```

Both return the following error:

```
ArgumentExecption was unhandled (The item with the specified name wasn't found).
```

This is the error line:

```
excelApp.ActiveChart.Shapes.Item(excelApp.ActiveChart.Name).Top = 100; 
// or excelApp.ActiveChart.Shapes.Item("mainChartView").Top = 100;
```

I really hope that one of you has the correct awnser, help is very appreciated!

edit: Solution was:

```
excelApp.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item("mainChartView").Top = 20;
```

Comment: Did you try to give/set your active chart a name?

Comment: I've allready found the awnser. I've tryed some other settings and found the working one myself. I've edited my question with the solution.

Comment: Please move your answer from your question into a new answer below, then mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found the anwser myself.

I replaced:

```
excelApp.ActiveChart.Shapes.Item(excelApp.ActiveChart.Name).Top = 100;
```

with:

```
excelApp.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item("mainChartView").Top = 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to use:

excelApp.ActiveChart.Parent.Top = 100;

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the .Parent Name property, shouldn't you be setting the name of the Chart object itself? Do you have the Chart object available? Set its name property

excelApp.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart should return a shape type (in your case chart). Set that types name property and then try

Comment: I've found the solution myself allready. But no, you really need to set the parent name, because else you will set the innerChart name. Wich is just Pie itself.